# Silverlight TreeView detect node expansion

Tags: silverlight, treeview

I must be missing something obvious - how can I detect when a node is expanded in a Silverlight TreeView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately "SelectedItemChanged" is not a routed event yet. So the closest you could get is using this:

```
treeView.AddHandler(TreeView.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp), true);

    void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is Path)
        {
            Path p = e.OriginalSource as Path;
            if (p.Name == "CheckedVisual" || p.Name == "UncheckedVisual")
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not appear to handle the case where we double-click on the node itself and it expands/contracts the node.

Answer (score 2):

Also the treeviewitems have an expanded event which I'm using currently but you'd have to attach to each node you add.

```
AddHandler t.Expanded, AddressOf TreeViewItem_Expanded
```